# Location of mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator parameter in hadoop installation

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I was working on mapreduce in java to read Key-Value type file separated by ':'. I figured how to parse the file (using **getConf().set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", ":")**;). I tried to find out the location where these parameters are stored but couldn't. I did a grep on the hadoop installation but there were no xml files which has set those parameters. According to the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) of Configuration class, I tried to find that value in mapred-default.xml but no luck.

Where can I find these values? This is also the case with some other parameters as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be present in mapred-site.xml. But, it is not added by default to the XML file. If for every job, you are using the same delimiter, then you can add this parameter to the `mapred-site.xml` file in your Hadoop installation.

This setting for this parameter is handled in code.

In `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueLineRecordReader.java` (check [KeyValueLineRecordReader.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/KeyValueLineRecordReader.java)), the value is set to tab ("\t") by default.

```
public static final String KEY_VALUE_SEPERATOR = 
"mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator";
```

The value is set in the constructor of `KeyValueLineRecordReader` class:

```
String sepStr = conf.get(KEY_VALUE_SEPERATOR, "\t");
```